# Order of receiving Win32 Events

Tags: winapi, events, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I have 3 different threads that use the Windows `SetEvent` API to set an event each.

```
DWORD thFunc1(LPVOID)
{
  ...
  SetEvent(event1);
  ...
}
DWORD thFunc2(LPVOID)
{
  ...
  SetEvent(event2);
  ...
}
DWORD thFunc3(LPVOID)
{
  ...
  SetEvent(event3);
  ...
}
```

A 4th thread is waiting on all of these events using `WaitForMultipleObjects` API.

```
DWORD thCatch(LPVOID)
{
  ...
  DWORD ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, arrHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);
  ...
}
```

My question is twofold:

1. If the 3 threads signal the event at almost the same timestamp, is the order of the events guaranteed to be received in the same order as they are sent?
2. If the answer to question 1 is NO, then is there any way that this can be achieved using Windows APIs?

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) API call makes a single promise when more than one object entered the signaled state:

> If multiple objects become signaled, the function returns the index of the first handle in the array whose object was signaled.

The order in which multiple objects are signaled cannot be determined from the `WaitForMultipleObjects` call.

If the order in which events happened is important, you will have to record that information elsewhere. You could use a [singly linked list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-singly-linked-lists) with atomic push and pop operations, and signal an event when a new entry arrived.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @IInspectable
Is there any documentation from Microsoft which verifies the that the order cannot be determined? I have gone through the documentation but did not find this information. Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: @ved Documentation works like this: Everything that's written is part of the formal contract. Everything that's not written is assumed to be unspecified. The documentation linked from this answer replicates the formal contract for the case where multiple objects become signaled. The API picks the documented order. It should be obvious that it cannot pick a different order (such as the order in which objects became signaled) at the same time.